# How to overwrite words by POS tag using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pos-tagger

How to overwrite words by POS tagging NLTK using pandas dataframe?

For Example I have:

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter='\t', names=columns)

data['POSTags'] = pos_tag_sents(data['Sentence'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist())
```

My input:

```
DAW1 was further investigated by
```

Output now:

```
[('DAW1', 'NNP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('further', 'RBR'), ('investigated', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN')]
```

What i need output:

```
NNP VBD RBR VBN IN
```